# Place htaccess file for all subdomains to redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have configured my server to accept any subdomain for

```
pinnaclerealestatesystems.com
```

(Its something like a virtual host). Its not pointing to any folder/path.

I've written the .htaccess code to redirect all the domains.. 
Now, i just want to know, where to place .htaccess file in my hosting.

You can try a sample subdomain to get a batter idea

```
http://abc.pinnaclerealestatesystems.com
```

I'm using Godaddy Hosting, Linux, Apache

Comment: Which code is returning `pageok` to browser for `http://abc.pinnaclerealestatesystems.com`

Comment: Its a default message, showing.. I dont know where is this file originally.. I couldn't find it in my whole hosting..

Comment: It seams to be a puppet message. Please check the page source code.

Comment: I saw source before commenting. You need to find out more info about your setup. For ex. what is `VirtualHost` entry for your subdomain?

Comment: Actually, I have configured my server to accept any subdomain. eventually, I want to redirect 
every subdomain to a folder(without registering/setting it up)..
for example: I want to redirect http://abc.pinnaclerealestatesystems.com ===>>> http://pinnaclerealestatesystems.com/abc AND, http://xyz.pinnaclerealestatesystems.com ===>>>
http://pinnaclerealestatesystems.com/xyz
So, Sub-domains can vary

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.pinnaclerealestatesystems\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by DocumentRoot? should I create a new directory?

Comment: You don't need to create `DocumentRoot`. That just means website root where your main `index.php` or `index.html` resides.